# Django formfield_for_foreignkey

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-1.7, django-modeladmin

I am trying to filter my admin choices in a foreign key field following the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey).

My model is pretty simple:

```
class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, default="Title")
    layout = models.ForeignKey(Layout, null=False) #This sets the layout for the current page
```

To achieve that i should do something like:

```
class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "layout":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Template.objects.get_a_queryset()
        return super(PageAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

It is working, but it is going through the function 3 times every time i access the page, giving a total of 5 querys(3 times plus 2 it has by default). It is passing 3 times the same db_field.

How can i reduce that to only 1 query? Is this an intended behaviour and if so...why?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what is going on but I have two tools to point your way:

1. [IPython](http://ipython.org/) embed

   ```
   from IPython import embed
   ... lots of code ...
   embed()
   ```

The shell where you run your dev server will drop into IPython where you embed() so you can explore the stack

2. [traceback](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) module

   ```
   import traceback
   ... lots of code ....
   traceback.print_stack()
   ```

This will print out the stack so you can differentiate the 3 invocations.

Comment: I have tried comparing differences between the invocations, but everything seems to be exactly the same (compared every argument)

Comment: I can take a look at this over the weekend and report back.